# on fire thrice because of the script

Tags: javascript, jquery

whenever i tried to select a date the on function is fired 3 times i tried removing this script 
and it does work, but the ui is ruined and also i noticed that onselect is not working.

```html
 <!Doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <!-- <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css"> -->
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        
        
        
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var newdate = new Date();
          $("#inputMultiDate").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            multidate: true,
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            onSelect: function(date){
             console.log(date);
            }
          }).on("change", function() {
            var dates = $('#inputMultiDate').val().split(',');
            alert(dates[0]);
          });;
        });</script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <input type="text" id="inputMultiDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick the multiple dates">
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSelect` is not working because `onSelect` is an option of *jQuery UI* datepicker, however you're using *Bootstrap* datepicker, which is a very different plugin.

Instead, boostrap datepicker uses events chained to the datepicker itself, like you have done with your `change`. *However*, given how the datepicker actually works behind the scenes, I'd imagine it changes the input multiple times, hence firing multiple alerts.

Instead of `change`, try [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate):

```js
var newdate = new Date();
$("#inputMultiDate").datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  multidate: true,
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
}).on("changeDate", function() {
  var dates = $(this).val().split(',');
  console.log(dates[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inputMultiDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick the multiple dates">
```

Comment: just wanna ask further more question, how am i suppose to get the date, because im getting this Fri Jan 18 2019 13:41:12 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time) output over and over again even.